# Confused about Google GCM XMPP

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a little bit confused about how to implement XMPP communication to GCM. Should I implement a XMPP server or a XMPP client on my server?

Thank you.

Comment: You only need XMPP with GCM if you want to use the "XMPP connection server". I suggest to have a look at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Answer (score 3):

You should implement a XMPP client on your server, which will establish a connection to the GCM CCS server.

As mentioned in a comment, you only need XMPP if you wish device to cloud messaging. For regular push notifications (cloud to device messaging), the GCM HTTP endpoint is sufficient.

Comment: @User I don't know what this has to do with iOS and Windows Mobile.