# sending and handling upstream messages GCM

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app which will get messages from GCM for different topics. I have a realative good idea of how I can do it for sending downstream messages, but I am confused and practically lost in knowing how to code (in any programming or scripting language) for receiving the upstream messages and handle them, for example, to register the client's ID. 
Could anybody share a snippet code for both receiving upstream messages (client->GCM->server) and handling the messages in the server side?

Comment: I posted a GCM server in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060099/google-gcm-xmpp-code-samples/32099039#32099039 that includes the ability to handle upstream messages

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I helped me out.